# How is my BehaviorSubject<T> being typed as 'never'?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm building a service file in angular using `BehaviorSubject`s inside of an object and am getting the following error in VS Code.

> Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.

I've used `BehaviorSubject`s in this same manner before so I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong in this instance.  I have a lot going on in the service file so I'll omit it to a singular instance of the type of pattern I'm trying to design.

```
//a set of values a user will select through an input.
export type MtSizeOptionType = '--'|'1'|'2'|'3'|'4'|'5'|'6'|'7'|'8'|'9'|'10'|'11'|
                           '12'|'13'|'14'|'15'|'16'|'17'|'18'|'19'|'20'|'21'|'22'|
                           '23'|'24'|'25'|'26'|'27'|'28'|'29'|'30'|'31'|'32'|'33'|
                           '34'|'35'|'36'|'37'|'38'|'39'|'40'|'41'|'42'|'43'|'44';


//a type for shaping one of the types of datasets I want to use.
export type MtSizeObserver = {
    params  : BehaviorSubject<MtSizeOptionType>,
    setting : BehaviorSubject<string>
};


//a type for allowing the data object to be shaped as one of these data types which I'm
//leaving out for brevity.
export type PropObserver = NumberObserver | StringObserver   | BoxSizeObserver |
                           MtSizeObserver | FontSizeObserver | LineSizeObserver;


//an interface to shape the data entries.
export interface MainObserver{  [key : string] : PropObserver;  }


//a function I import into the service file to create a string to store as a setting.
export function CreateMtSize(size: string): string { return `mt-${size}`; }



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ResponsiveShellService {

    //the data object
    private PropertyMaster : MainObserver = {
        CrushGapWSetting: {
            params  : new BehaviorSubject<MtSizeOptionType>('--'),
            setting : new BehaviorSubject<string>('mt-1')
        },
        //all the other elements
    }

    constructor(){}

    //the function where I attempt to update the CrushGapWSetting
    public updateCrushGapW(val: MtSizeOptionType){

        const defaultSize: string = '--mt-1';

        this.PropertyMaster.CrushGapWSetting.params.next(val); //error

        if(val === '--'){
            this.PropertyMaster.CrushGapWSetting.setting.next(defaultSize);  //error
        }
        else {
            this.PropertyMaster.CrushGapWSetting.setting.next(CreateMtSize(val));  //error
        }

    }
}
```

Each `.next()` in the `updateCrushGapW()` function throws the *not assignable to parameter type of 'never'* error and I don't understand how it's typed as `never`.  Can anyone see how this is happening?  If you need to see the other types let me know and I'll add those in.

Comment: provide initial value for BehaviourSubject. BehaviourSubject requires initial value.

You can check here - https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided us with what `NumberObserver`, `StringObserver` etc is. My guess is that they all indirectly point to an object with a function "next", but the parameter type of each "next" is a different type.

Here is a simpler example of how to get the "is not assignable to parameter type of 'never'".

```
interface NumberObserver {
  next(v:number) : void;
}

interface StringObserver {
  next(v:string) : void;
}


type PropObserver = NumberObserver | StringObserver;;

interface MainObserver { [key: string] : PropObserver; }


const PropertyMaster : MainObserver = {};

PropertyMaster.CrushGapWSettings.next("hello"); // << == Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'
```

`CrushGapWSettings` is the union of type `NumberObserver` and `StringObserver`.

If you don't cast it to a specific type, you can operate on the *intersection* of every type in the union.

TypeScript will only allow you to do things with the intersection if that thing is valid for every member of the intersection .

They both have a method `next`, so you can access the function `next`.
This function's parameter is the intersection of type `number` and `string`. (`number & string`) The intersection of two basic types is `never`. (`number & string = never`).